# CodeIgniter post request status 403

Tags: php, codeigniter, post, http-status-code-403

Hi I am totally beginner on CI, I am trying to work with a CI script to learn on it.Codes are quit big cant share here and I am not so sure exactly which part do you need that's why I posted it into 3rd party site and linked bellow

[Here is my codes for a form](https://codeshare.io/G8ogEe)
and  [here is controller](https://codeshare.io/5QLQyL) ,and bellow is a screenshot of the form

[image]

On the form when I put information correctly and click submit button this not giving any error but information's are not saved,and fetch old data.I checked from `inspection->network` and I found POST request is 403 error.bellow is screenshot of inspection element
[image]

I already changed `upload` folder and sub folders `permission 0777`but this doesn't work.

I found 2 htaccess file

```
1.public_html/.htaccess

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
</IfModule>


2.public_html/application/.htacess

<IfModule authz_core_module>
  Require all denied
</IfModule>
<IfModule !authz_core_module>
  Deny from all
 </IfModule>
```

I am not so sure what else information do you need to help on this ,whatever you need please leave a comment or I am ok to provide full source code

this information found on log file when click on

```
DEBUG - 2019-06-16 00:53:30 --> File loaded: /home/exhakduz/mydomain.com/application/views/common/admin/header.php
DEBUG - 2019-06-16 00:53:30 --> File loaded: /home/exhakduz/mydomain.com/application/views/common/admin/navigation.php
DEBUG - 2019-06-16 00:53:30 --> File loaded: /home/exhakduz/mydomain.com/application/modules/settings/views/site_settings.php
DEBUG - 2019-06-16 00:53:30 --> File loaded: /home/exhakduz/mydomain.com/application/views/common/admin/footer.php
DEBUG - 2019-06-16 00:53:30 --> File loaded: /home/exhakduz/mydomain.com/application/views/templates/admin-template.php
INFO - 2019-06-16 00:53:30 --> Final output sent to browser
DEBUG - 2019-06-16 00:53:30 --> Total execution time: 1.9082
```

no informations in error log

Comment: 403 is an authentication error. Check which controller and action it calls, and if any middleware prohibits that. Lastly check the debug logs in `storage/logs/*.log`

Comment: Updated my post and added debug log ,and other 2 of your suggestion I don't know what to do ,if you don't can I send you my source code and can you check for me please? thank you

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you have the problem with CSRF protection.
Lets check it whether the CSRF config has been enable:

`application/config.php
...
$config['csrf_protection'] = FALSE; // TRUE`

Answer (score 0):

Error on "contact map" field,html characters was conflicted